# sizeof() a struct with a zero length array member

Tags: c, gcc, sizeof, c99, flexible-array-member

I'm confused about `sizeof()` output in C. Say I have:

```
struct foo {
    char a;
    char b;
    char c;
    char d[0];
};
```

I would expect `sizeof(struct foo)` to be 4. However, it returns 3 after compiling with gcc. Also, when compiling the code with strict settings `-pedantic-errors`, I get compiler errors.

Can someone help me understand this behavior?

Comment: What if you change the `0` to `1` or higher ?

Comment: Declaring an array with 0 elements is not valid C. It is accepted by GCC (and some other implementations) as an extension.

Comment: Could you flag for this to be CW? It seems like a good C FAQ candidate.

Comment: I took the liberty to add some extra information to the post, since someone has now added this question to the [C FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info). I hope you don't mind - it only means that your question will get positive extra attention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An array size of 0 is not legal.  Section 6.7.6.2p1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Array Declarators states:

> In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword static , the `[`
>   and `]` may delimit an expression or
>   `*` . **If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the expression shall have an integer type.  If the expression
>   is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero.** 
>   The element type shall not be an incomplete or function type.   The 
>   optional  type  qualifiers  and  the  keyword static shall  appear 
>   only  in  a declaration  of  a  function  parameter  with  an  array 
>   type,  and  then  only  in  the  outermost array type derivation.

So because this violates a constraint, this definition invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That being said, some compilers allow a zero length array as the last member of a `struct` as an extension.  [GCC does this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html).  In this case, it works the same as a flexible array member.

The standard compliant way to do this is to leave the size blank:

```
struct foo {
    char a;
    char b;
    char c;
    char d[];
};
```

In both cases, the flexible array member is not included in the size of the structure, which is why you get 3 for the size instead of 4 (although the presence of padding in a struct is up to the implementation).  This also means that such a struct cannot be a member of an array (at least not without some fishy manual pointer manipulation).

The way you would use such a struct would be to dynamically allocate space for it plus a number of elements of the last member.  For example:

```
struct foo *my_foo = malloc(sizeof(*my_foo) + (sizeof(char) * number_of_elements));
```

Comment: It's not legal but actually implemented as a [GNU extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So does gcc interpret this as a pointer to the end of the struct?

Comment: @marcantonio It actually points to the flexible array member which is after the other members.

Comment: The _flexible array member_ syntax was standardized in C99, but several compilers before that (e.g. GCC and MSVC) supported it with a pre-standard syntax of using 0 as the array length. Those compilers choke on the standard syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`char d[0]` is an array of chars with size 0. Which means it doesn't take up any space, since `sizeof(char) * 0 = 0`.

Comment: Normally an array decays into a pointer that points to `&d[0]`, but since you're using a zero size array that element doesn't exist. So I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: How is decay relevant here?

Comment: @R.. It was asked in the comment above that has currently been removed.